# SetNamedSecurityInfo takes a writeable path; how big should the buffer be?

Tags: winapi, path, constants

[SetNamedSecurityInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setnamedsecurityinfoa) is defined as taking an `LPTSTR`, not an  `LPCTSTR`. Now the standard Win32 API that takes a `LPTSTR` also has some way of indicating the necessary buffer length. Sometimes that's explicit in the signature, sometimes it's documented as `MAX_PATH` or otherwise. Not so for `SetNamedSecurityInfo`.

To be honest, I have no idea why `SetNamedSecurityInfo` would want to **write** to that buffer, but perhaps it tries to canonicalize a path in-place. But then I might need to support 32768 characters?

Comment: I guess they just mistyped the type, should be const.

Comment: formally, of course, this cannot be proved (what is considered evidence?) but name can point to constant, read-only memory. this api never try modify name - really this not need by sense. name need be converted to native format from win32 format, before open object handle, but this anyway can not be done in place - always new buffer allocated for final native path. here no situation like `CreateProcessW` when api temporary want write 0 in cmdline, if application name not provided

Comment: The document says it is identified as a null-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the document [SetNamedSecurityInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-setnamedsecurityinfoa)

> pObjectName
>
> A pointer to a **null-terminated string** that specifies the name of the
>   object for which to set security information.

That means the buffer length which will be sent into the function is always related to the string length of the buffer.

Comment: That null is where **you** the caller place the end of the string input. But the parameter is non-const, it's apparently modified by the callee. But how?

Comment: There are no instructions in the document that the caller will modify its value, even if you pass a value of type `LPTSTR` in a function, you don't necessarily have to modify its value in it. Compared with defined as `LPCSTR`, it's just not rigorous enough.